# ¿Cómo Autoajustar el ancho de una columna de un JTable al contenido que hay en ella?

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un `JTable` el cual lleno de forma dinámica con un `Stored Procedure`, el contenido de cada columna varia según la información que haya en la Base de Datos. Lo que ocupo es saber como se pueden ajustar las columnas al contenido que haya en ellas.

He visto muchos ejemplos, en los que se fija el ancho de manera manual a las columnas, pero, el problema que le encuentro es que si como developer le doy un ancho fijo y el contenido es mas chico, tendré un espacio en blanco que se vera mal y si es mayor, no mostrara todo el contenido, es por eso que busco la forma de que el ancho de la columna quede justo al contenido.

**Llenado del `JTable`**

```
public void loadTambleEmployees(){
    DefaultTableModel modelTable = new DefaultTableModel();
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato1");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato2");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato3");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato4");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato5");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato6");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato7");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato8");
    modelTable.addColumn("Dato9");

    for (Employee loadAllEmployee : Functions.getCurrentFunctions().loadAllEmployees()) {
        modelTable.addRow(new Object[]{loadAllEmployee.getDato1(), loadAllEmployee.getDato2(),
                    loadAllEmployee.getDato3(), loadAllEmployee.getDato4(), loadAllEmployee.getDato5(),
                    loadAllEmployee.getDato6(), loadAllEmployee.getDato7(), loadAllEmployee.getDato8(),
                    loadAllEmployee.getDato9()});
    }
    tblEmployees.setModel(modelTable);      
}
```

Ya intente utilizar:

```
tblEmployees.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

Y

```
tblEmployees.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Sin tener éxito

Comment: ¿intentaste usar modelTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS) ?

Comment: Voy a Probar el código

Comment: @PakLei no me funciono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve buscando una respuesta a mi pregunta y la encontré **[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627431/auto-resizing-the-jtable-column-widths/17627497#17627497)** en la pagina de **`stackoverflow`** en ingles

```
/**
 * Metodo que ajusta el ancho de la columna de una tabla
 * @param table 
 */
private void resizeColumnWidth(JTable table) {
    //Se obtiene el modelo de la columna
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    //Se obtiene el total de las columnas
    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        //Establecemos un valor minimo para el ancho de la columna
        int width = 150; //Min Width
        //Obtenemos el numero de filas de la tabla
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            //Obtenemos el renderizador de la tabla
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            //Creamos un objeto para preparar el renderer
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            //Establecemos el width segun el valor maximo del ancho de la columna
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);

        }
        //Se establece una condicion para no sobrepasar el valor de 300
        //Esto es Opcional
        if (width > 300) {
            width = 300;
        }
        //Se establece el ancho de la columna
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
}
```

Ya implementada la solución quedaría así:

```
    //Se cargan los elementos de la tabla
    loadEmployeesTable();     
    //Se llama al metodo que ajusta las columnas
    resizeColumnWidth(tblEmployees);
    //Se desactiva el Auto Resize de la tabla
    //Es importante que vaya despues de el metodo que ajusta el ancho de la columna
    tblEmployees.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```